# CSS file 404 not found of CSS on nginx

Tags: html, css, nginx

I am trying to deploy a static website on my server with nginx, the HTML file is fine but the CSS file cannot be loaded.
My config file is:

```
location /index/ {
    alias /var/www/html/my_domnain.com/Myindex/;
    autoindex on;
    index MyIndex.html;
}
```

The head of MyIndex.html is like this:

```
<head>
…
<link href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
…
</head>
```

I put both `fonts.css` and `MyIndex.html` in the `/var/www/html/my_domnain.com/Myindex/` path. MyIndex.html can display but the CSS file is not loaded. The console shows:

```
GET https://my_domain.com/index/fonts.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Also, I have the same problem with the logo.jpeg I am trying to use. Why cannot nginx find the file I put in the same folder? Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have any other `location` blocks in your configuration? Particularly one that might match URIs which end with `.css` or `.jpeg`?

Comment: Is the misspelling of the directory name in `alias /var/www/html/my_domnain.com/Myindex/;` reflected in the filesystem?

Comment: No, but when I change /var/www/html/my_domnain.com/Myindex/; to /var/www/html/my_domnain.com/index/;  it worked. But I don't know why they have to match with each other.